# Slow loading of WordPress site on development server despite fast database queries

Tags: wordpress, debian, virtual-machine

Oracle VM
Host: Windows 11 Pro
Guest: Debian 11

I have a WordPress site hosted on my development server that loads extremely slowly. Upon accessing the page, it takes over 2 minutes to load, even though the database queries take less than 0.1 seconds. Interestingly, the Firefox Inspector reports a load time of only 26 seconds during the page load, which is still too slow.

Other web applications on the same server run significantly faster, so I'm confident the issue is specific to this WordPress site.

Could someone take a look at the attached diagram and see if there's anything apparent causing the slow loading? Are there possible reasons or configuration settings I might have overlooked?

I've already checked the following:

- Database queries are fast and efficient.
- Other web applications on the server don't exhibit similar performance issues.
- Server resources seem sufficient.

Here's the diagram illustrating the page loading process:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Install Query Monitor and see what queries are running on this specific address. From there you can narrow the problem.

Comment: I already did that. I recorded all the Queries in this session. And when I let them run with an SQL Client they only take less than 0.1 seconds all together. So this is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Is it slow when you are logged as admin or its the same for guest user ? Also test on blank page what is the loading time then add content till you face the issue maybe ? Turn off plugins maybe ? Also notice this is in backend request to add the post in the trash ? Is that the only case where you face this issue ?